# API Trigger Sends only deploy to existing customers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, triggered-send

We're creating a Triggered Send and it is sending to addresses that are already in All Subscribers, but not anyone who is completely new to the client... We are sending both the SubKey and Email, and have checked "Add users to this List" (being All Subs) and the Triggered Send DE.

Has anyone encountered this?

I've been researching as best as I can here, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have Subscriber key feature. How many fields of type "email address" does your triggered send DE have? If zero or more than one, this will happen. Reason is, the sendout will try to look at the DE for determining the email address to deliver to. If unclear, it will look at All Subscribers for the email address as a fallback. If that's empty, no sendout. Which would explain the difference between known and unknown recipients you describe.

Comment: @JonasLamberty - would that also be true if a field is called "Email" but the data type is Text?

Comment: @GeorgeRosedale - you need to have one, and only one field in your sendable DE of type Email Address. Otherwise it will send only to those, which email addresses can be looked up in All Subscribers based on Subscriber Key

Comment: Yes, only 1 field with data type of Email Address... but, we did have another field called "Email" but it is text data type, not Email

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is that the names not sent were in a holding pattern due to "CONTACT DELETE" process.  Therefore, our trigger was always fine. Thank you for the feedback to help troubleshoot.